# customised loss function in keras using theano function

Tags: python, theano, keras

I'd like to use my own binary_crossentropy instead of using the one that comes with Keras library. Here is my custom function:

```
    import theano
    from keras import backend as K

    def elementwise_multiply(a, b): # a and b are tensors
       c = a * b
       return theano.function([a, b], c)

    def custom_objective(y_true, y_pred):  
       first_log = K.log(y_pred)
       first_log = elementwise_multiply(first_log, y_true)
       second_log = K.log(1 - y_pred)
       second_log = elementwise_multiply(second_log, (1 - y_true))
       result = second_log + first_log
       return K.mean(result, axis=-1)
```

> note: This is for practice. I'm aware of
>   T.nnet.binary_crossentropy(y_pred, y_true)

But, when I compile the model:

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss = custom_objective, optimizer = sgd)
```

I get this error:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        36 
>        37 sgd = SGD(lr=0.001)
>   ---> 38 model.compile(loss = custom_objective, optimizer = sgd)
>        39 # ==============================================
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in
>   compile(self, optimizer, loss, class_mode)
>       418         else:
>       419             mask = None
>   --> 420         train_loss = weighted_loss(self.y, self.y_train, self.weights, mask)
>       421         test_loss = weighted_loss(self.y, self.y_test, self.weights, mask)
>       422
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py in
>   weighted(y_true, y_pred, weights, mask)
>        80         '''
>        81         # score_array has ndim >= 2
>   ---> 82         score_array = fn(y_true, y_pred)
>        83         if mask is not None:
>        84             # mask should have the same shape as score_array
>
> in custom_objective(y_true, y_pred)
>        11     second_log = K.log(1 - K.clip(y_true, K.epsilon(), np.inf))
>        12     second_log = elementwise_multiply(second_log, (1-y_true))
>   ---> 13     result = second_log + first_log
>        14     #result = np.multiply(result, y_pred)
>        15     return K.mean(result, axis=-1)
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Function' and
>   'Function'

when I replace elementwise_multiply with inline function:

```
def custom_objective(y_true, y_pred):  
    first_log = K.log(y_pred)    
    first_log = first_log * y_true
    second_log = K.log(1 - y_pred)
    second_log = second_log * (1-y_true)
    result = second_log + first_log
    return K.mean(result, axis=-1)
```

the model compiles but the loss value is **nan**:

> Epoch 1/1 945/945 [==============================] - 62s - loss: nan -
>   acc: 0.0011 - val_loss: nan - val_acc: 0.0000e+00

Could someone help me with this please?!

Thanks

Comment: The error message seems to indicate `result = second_log + first_log` being the error as these are both functions. Have you checked the output of `K.log`?

Comment: @M.T yes, the output of K.log is "Elemwise{log,no_inplace}.0". I just updated the question (added another scenario where the model compiles but loss is nan)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem. I had to multiply the return value by "-1" as I'm using stochastic gradient decedent (sgd) as optimiser and not stochastic gradient ascent!

Here is the code and it works like a charm:

```
import theano
from keras import backend as K

def custom_objective(y_true, y_pred):  
    first_log = K.log(y_pred)    
    first_log = first_log * y_true
    second_log = K.log(1 - y_pred)
    second_log = second_log * (1 - y_true)
    result = second_log + first_log
    return (-1 * K.mean(result))
```